# Clear Style to standard output expressions in the same cell

Tags: color, style, output

I would like to reset an expression in a Standar Output inside a Cell.

For example,

```
c + Style[a+b, Red] (*I want the a+b part in red *)

Style[%, Blue]  (*Now I would like all the expression in Blue or Black*)
```

The last output will give   **c+(     )** in blue but the inside parenthesis  **a +b** will remain red, because this is equivalent to

```
Style[c + Style[a + b, Red], Red]
```

But I want  my last  Output as

```
Style[c + a + b, Red]
```

This would be simple if there would be a way to clear all the  **%**  style.

Comment: maybe `Style[ToExpression@StripBoxes@ToBoxes@%, Blue]`?

Comment: ... or `Style[% /. Style -> (# &), Blue]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
c + Style[a + b, Red]
Style[% /. Style -> (# &), Blue, 24]
```

[image]

```
c + Style[a + b, Red]

Style[% /. Style -> (HoldForm@# &), Blue, 24]

ReleaseHold @ %
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After many hours trying to solve this, I found out that with simply

```
c + Style[a + b, Red]
%/. Style[x__, y__] -> x
```

clear the Style. Thanks all!!